# Override custom registration conventions in StructureMap 3

Tags: c#, generics, registration, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm using `CQRS` pattern in my recent project and used `Structuremap 3` as my `IoC Container`, So I defined following conversion to resolve `ICommandHandlers` for each `BaseEntity` types:

```
 public class InsertCommandRegistrationConvention 
    : StructureMap.Graph.IRegistrationConvention
{
    private static readonly Type _openHandlerInterfaceType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>);
    private static readonly Type _openInsertCommandType = typeof(InsertCommandParameter<>);
    private static readonly Type _openInsertCommandHandlerType = typeof(InsertCommandHandler<>);

    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type) &&
            type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && 
                x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAggregateRoot<>)))
        {
            Type closedInsertCommandType = _openInsertCommandType.MakeGenericType(type);
            Type closedInsertCommandHandlerType =
                _openInsertCommandHandlerType.MakeGenericType(type);

            Type insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType =
                _openHandlerInterfaceType.MakeGenericType(closedInsertCommandType);
            registry.For(insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType)
                .Use(closedInsertCommandHandlerType);
        }
    }
}
```

and used it in my CompositionRoot:

```
public static class ApplicationConfiguration
{
    public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(s =>
            {
                s.TheCallingAssembly();
                s.WithDefaultConventions();
                s.Convention<InsertCommandRegistrationConvention>();
            });
        });

        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
}
```

so for each my entity it register appropriate `InsertCommandHandler` for example it register

the `InsertCommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Order>>` for `ICommandHandler<ICommandParameter<Order>>`

sometimes I need to register custom `InsertCommandHandler`s for some Entities for example for `Product` I want to register non-generic `InsertProductCustomCommandHandler` class for `ICommandHandler<ICommandParameter<Product>>` instead `InsertCommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Product>>`(in the other word, I want to override the `InsertCommendRegistrationConvention`).

How could I do this, with Structuremap 3?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the method `IContainer.Configure()` - the `Configure()` method allows you to add additional configuration to an existing `Container` or `ObjectFactory`

I've simplified your abstractions to demonstrate this in action:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity { }
public interface ICommandHandler<T> { }
public class ClassA : BaseEntity { }
public class ClassB : BaseEntity { }
public class ClassC : BaseEntity { }
public class ClassD : BaseEntity { }
public class InsertCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T> { }
public class SpecialInsertDCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<ClassD> { }
```

And `InsertCommandRegistrationConvention`

```
public class InsertCommandRegistrationConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    private static readonly Type _openHandlerInterfaceType = 
        typeof(ICommandHandler<>);
    private static readonly Type _openInsertCommandHandlerType = 
        typeof(InsertCommandHandler<>);

    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            Type closedInsertCommandHandlerType =
                _openInsertCommandHandlerType.MakeGenericType(type);

            Type insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType =
                _openHandlerInterfaceType.MakeGenericType(type);

            registry.For(insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType)
                .Use(closedInsertCommandHandlerType);
        }
    }
}
```

This test demonstrates that a container configured with `InsertCommandRegistrationConvention` will return the generic `InsertCommandHandler<>` for all 4 of the test classes `ClassA` to `ClassD`

```
[Test]
public void Handle_Initialize_RegistersClassesAToDToReturnInsertCommandHandler()
{
    var container = ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

    var resultA = container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<ClassA>>();
    var resultB = container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<ClassB>>();
    var resultC = container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<ClassC>>();
    var resultD = container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<ClassD>>();

    Assert.That(resultA.GetType() == typeof(InsertCommandHandler<ClassA>));
    Assert.That(resultB.GetType() == typeof(InsertCommandHandler<ClassB>));
    Assert.That(resultC.GetType() == typeof(InsertCommandHandler<ClassC>));
    Assert.That(resultD.GetType() == typeof(InsertCommandHandler<ClassD>));
}
```

And this test shows the `Configure` method successfully updates the registration for `ClassD` to return `SpecialInsertDCommandHandler` instead of `InsertCommandHandler<ClassD>`

```
[Test]
public void Handle_Condfigure_OverridesRegistrationForClassD()
{
    var container = ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

    container.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.For<ICommandHandler<ClassD>>().Use<SpecialInsertDCommandHandler>();
    });

    var resultD = container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<ClassD>>();

    Assert.That(resultD.GetType() == typeof(SpecialInsertDCommandHandler));
}
```

Comment: I used `container.Configure()`, but when I run `WhatDoIHave()`, it shows that for `ICommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Calendar>>` structuremap uses both `InsertCommandHandler<Calendar>` as (Default) and custom `InsertCalendarCommandHandler`(but not as Default).

Comment: Hi @Masoud - my code shows them the other way around which is a little puzzling - did you add the custom registration after the call to `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();`?

Comment: You are right, I used `container.Configure()` instead `container.Initialize()` for generic `InsertCommandHandlers`, after fixing it, now `InsertCalendarCommandHandler` is default and `ICommandHandler<InsertCommandParameter<Calendar>>` isn't. but my program is modular and I couldn't have one `Initialize()` per each module. so I have to have one 'Initialize' for the program and one `Configure` for each module.

Comment: @Masoud it should still work. The trick would be to call all of the Modules, each of which can call `ObjectFactory.Configure()` and then move on to overriding registrations with the custom types. My understanding is that for *StructureMap* the last registration is the default one.

Comment: But I checked, running 2 or more Initialize() cause, the earlier registrations be rewritten.

Comment: @Masoud yes that's right. `ObjectFactory.Initialize` and `ObjectFactory.Configure` have the same signature so change each module to use `ObjectFactory.Configure` to build up the configuration across the modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the convention to say something like "If there's a specific command handler, use that.  Otherwise, use the InsertCommandHandler."

It would look like this (like qujck, I simplified the classes):

```
public class InsertCommandRegistrationConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    private static readonly Type _openHandlerInterfaceType = typeof (ICommandHandler<>);
    private static readonly Type _openInsertCommandHandlerType = typeof (InsertCommandHandler<>);
    private static readonly IList<Type> _customCommandHandlerTypes;

    static InsertCommandRegistrationConvention()
    {
        _customCommandHandlerTypes = _openInsertCommandHandlerType
            .Assembly
            .ExportedTypes
            .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract)
            .Where(x => !x.IsGenericType || x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof (InsertCommandHandler<>))
            .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>)))
            .ToArray();
    }

    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract && typeof (BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            var insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType = _openHandlerInterfaceType.MakeGenericType(type);
            var closedInsertCommandHandlerType = _openInsertCommandHandlerType.MakeGenericType(type);

            // check for any classes that implement ICommandHandler<T> that are not also InsertCommandHandler<T>
            var customHandler = _customCommandHandlerTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType));

            registry.For(insertclosedHandlerInterfaceType)
                .Use(customHandler ?? closedInsertCommandHandlerType);
        }
    }
}
```

The classes I used:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity { }
public class Class1 : BaseEntity { }
public class Class2 : BaseEntity { }
public class SpecialClass :BaseEntity { }

public interface ICommandHandler<T> { }
public class InsertCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<T> { }
public class SpecialClassInsertCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SpecialClass> { }
```

The tests that pass:

```
        Assert.That(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<Class1>>(), Is.InstanceOf<InsertCommandHandler<Class1>>());
        Assert.That(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<Class2>>(), Is.InstanceOf<InsertCommandHandler<Class2>>());
        Assert.That(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<SpecialClass>>(), Is.InstanceOf<SpecialClassInsertCommandHandler>());
```

The advantage is that you modified your convention, rather than avoided using it for certain items.  Which keeps everything in one spot if something about your logic has to change.